# Chrome extension and jQuery ajax query

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension

So basicly I can't use variables that were created by website in my Chrome extension but can I make jQuery ajax query to this site? Like I found that site is using something like this

```
/ajax/groups/members/remove.php?group_id=111111111111&uid=1111111111
```

Can I do that with my extension that will contain jQuery.ajax code? Tbh I have never used jQuery.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please rephrase your question. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to use ajax code in my Chrome extension but I don't know if I can because Chrome extensions can't access things belonging to website

Comment: Chrome extensions can do pretty much anything given the permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me clear some concepts for you:

1- Your chrome extension has a background page and it is completely different than the current tab that the user is viewing (you referred to it as website).

2- You can access tabs (including the current active tab) with chrome.tab API
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs

3- You can load jquery in your chrome extension background and you can send ajax requests with it. Also, you have to set required permissions for your chrome extension to be able to access outside domains.

4- If you send a ajax request with this path `"/ajax/groups/members/remove.php?group_id=111111111111&uid=1111111111"` in your chrome extension, it tried to load it from your localhost because your chrome extension loads from your localhost. Therefore, you have to write complete path such as `"//www.mydomain.com/ajax/groups/members/remove.php?group_id=111111111111&uid=1111111111"`